# @CollectionOfElements without create the apposite table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, annotations

***EDIT***

Hi all.

**WHAT I TRY TO GET**

I want a table that represents a list of personal details, this table is called PERSON and must have this columns:

```
ID      NAME    SURNAME     STREET      ID_CITY
```

Well, i already have a table in my db that contains all municipalities of my country, this table is called MUNICIPALITY and has this columns:

```
ID      COUNTRY     PROVINCE    NAME
```

I wrote the class **Municipality.java** to reepresents the table above, this class is:

```
@Entity
public class Municipality implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
private String country;
private String province;
private String name;

public Municipality() {
}

...
```

So, i thought a good implementation of PERSON table is to write an emebedded class Address.java that contains some info about "the address" of the person to embed in the Person.java class.
**Address.java** simpy contains a street and a municipality object:

```
@Embeddable
public class Address implements Serializable {

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="ID_CITY")
@Cascade(CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
private Municipality municipality;
@Column(length=45)
private String street;

public Address() {
}

...
```

Address is simply emebedded in **Person.java** class:

```
@Entity
public class Person implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
private String name;
private String surname;
@Embedded
private Address address;

public Person() {
}

...
```

Well, if now i save a Person instance:

```
Person p=new Person();
Address a=new Address();
a.setStreet("bla bla");
Municipality mun=new Municipality();
mun.setName("ZZZ");
a.setMunicipality(mun);
p.setAddress(a);

session.save(p);
```

All works fine, hibernate create a table PERSON exactly how i want.

---

**THE PROBLEM**

But now, i want also the list of all address associate to a municipality object, so i do not necessary do a "select" for this.
I thougth i good thing is to add a collectin of Address to Municipality:

```
@CollectionOfElements
private List<Address> addressList;
```

But now if i save a person, hibernate create a new table MUNICIPALITY_ADDRESSLIST:

```
MUNICIPALITY_ID     ID_CITY     STREET
```

The table above contains always NULL values... so is totally useless, and i don't want it!

I read some docs about @CollectionOfElements and @OneToMany and i find i can define a join table. So i thought to set PERSON like join table...

```
@CollectionOfElements
@JoinTable(name="PERSON")
private List<Address> addressList;
```

First insert of Person works good, i obtain the PERSON table how i want, and MUNICIPALITY_ADDRESSLIST is no longer created.
But when i make the second insert, hibernate add a column to PERSON table: **MUNICIPALITY_ID**

```
ID      STREET      NAME    SURNAME     ID_CITY     MUNICIPALITY_ID
```

MUNICIPALITY_ID contains always NULL values, so why this column is added?

Sure my implementations is very bad, im new to hibernate and JPA, so where is my main mistake?

I hope now is more understandable... sorry for my bad english.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i think to find a solution... i do this:

```
@Entity
public class Municipality implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
private String country;
private String province;
private String name;
@OneToMany(mappedBy="address.municipality")
private List<Person> persons;

public Municipality() {
}

...
```

I have not changed other classes.

Is this correct or work only by chance?

Thanks.

Comment: It seems right! But According to The answer provided by yourself. You have a **bi-directional** relationship between Person and Municipality (Through @Embeddable Address), which **needs** mappedBy attribute. Notice when using a bi-directional relationship, **It is a good idea to use add convenience method to set up both sides**. Keep this in mind

Answer (score 2):

blow, if you do not really want *MUNICIPALITY_ADDRESSLIST* Table, you should use @Transient instead of @CollectionOfElements

```
public class Municipality {

    @Transient
    private List<Address> addressList;

}
```

If you use @CollectionOfElements, Hibernate will always create *MUNICIPALITY_ADDRESSLIST* Table. If @Transient does not fullfil your needs, provide more info about what you want to get

UPDATE

According to info provided by yourself

Person *has* an @Embedded Address which has a @ManyToOne relationship with Municipality

```
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    private Long id;

    @Embedded
    private Address address;

}
```

Now, our Address

```
/*
 * @Embeddable class MUST implements Serializable
 */
@Embeddable
public class Address implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne
    /*
     * If you are using Hibernate INSTEAD OF JPA
     * Prefer to use @Cascade Hibernate annotation, as shown bellow, 
     * instead of JPA cascade Attribute
     *
     * Also notice it can not be null - see nullable Attribute
     */   
    @Cascade(CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
    @JoinColumn(name="MUNICIPALITY_ID", nullable=false)
    private Municipality municipality;

}
```

And Municipality (without ANY List of Address or Person)

```
public class Municipality {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    private Long id;

}
```

As shown above, your DB structure should looks like

```
PERSON
ID
MUNICIPALITY_ID

MUNICIPALITY
ID
```

But whether Municipality has a List of Person as follows

```
public class Municipality {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany
    private List<Person> personList;

}
```

You will get The same structure shown above

But **you have a bi-directional relationship** Person can see Municipality (Through Address class) and Municipality can see Person (Through List of Person)

Now let's see The following scenario

```
Person person = new Person();
Municipality municipality = new Municipality();

Address address = new Address();
address.setMunicipality(person);

person.setAddress(address);

session.save(person);
```

You will see

```
INSERT INTO PERSON blah, blah, blah...
```

Because of @Cascade(SAVE_UPDATE)

```
INSERT INTO MUNICIPALITY blah, blah, blah...
```

But because of The bi-directional relationship, You should set up which property is The owner of The relationship. Owner of The relationship ? What is that ?

Suppose

```
public class A {

    @ManyToOne
    private B b;

}
```

And

```
public class B {

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="B_ID")
    @Cascade(SAVE_UPDATE)
    private List<A> aList;

}
```

And you do

```
/*
 * a.getB() is null, right ?
A a = new A();

B b = new B();
b.getAList().add(a);
```

SQL outputs

```
/* Let's suppose B_ID generated value is 5
INSERT INTO B 

/*
 * because of @Cascade(SAVE_UPDATE)
INSERT INTO A (B_ID) VALUES(5)
```

But because a.getB() is null

You will also see

```
UPDATE A SET B_ID = null
```

It explains why you should use mappedBy attribute when using a bi-directional relationship.

Comment: Hi! mmm... @transient is not what i want. I edit my post so i hope to explain the situation better. I know you can help me!!

Comment: Thank you now I think I have understand! You have been very clear.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the expected result is exactly (I'm too lazy to reproduce the case) but you should be able to derive the following sample:

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.CollectionOfElements(targetElement = java.lang.String.class)
@JoinTable( name="PHONE",joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="STUDENT_ID"))
@Column(name="PHONE_NO")
public Set<String> getPhones() {
```

Comment: I tried this:
    @CollectionOfElements
    @JoinTable(name="person",    joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="id_municipality"))
    private List<Address> addressList;

But doesn't work properly

Comment: in hibernate javadoc about targetElement: Represent the element class in the collection Only useful if the collection does not use generics